# React native calendars height issue

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, calendar

Basically I am using react native calendars I am facing the calendars height issue.

When I use my application on big screen sizes like tablet in portrait mode, calendars look fine in parent view, but when I run the same on small devices like a phone, I see only 3 rows of calendar.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6bkE.png)

I have been trying everything for the last 3 days but nothing works for me.

```
<View style={{ width: wd * 0.87, flex: 0.50 }}>
  <View style={{ flex: 0.15, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#000000', fontSize: moderateScale(17) }}>Select Date</Text>
  </View>

  <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#EBF3FF', borderRadius: moderateScale(20), overflow: 'hidden',flex:0.85 }}>
    <Calendar
      // dayLabelsWrapperStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 50 }}
      showSixWeeks={true}
      showWeekNumbers={false}
      onDayPress={(day) => {
        setSelected(day.dateString);
      }}
      markedDates={{
        [selected]: { selected: true, disableTouchEvent: true, selectedDotColor: 'orange' },
      }}
      style={{  }}
      theme={{
        calendarBackground: 'transparent',
        arrowColor: '#848A95',
        selectedDayTextColor: '#ffffff',
        selectedDayBackgroundColor: '#94ADFD',
        textMonthFontSize:moderateScale(14),
      dayTextColor:'green',
      textDayFontSize:moderateScale(12),
      // textDayHeaderFontSize:moderateScale(269),
        textDayHeaderFontWeight: 'bold',
        'stylesheet.calendar.header': {
          dayHeader: {
            color: 'black',
          },
          
        },
      }}
    />
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: The system and the program works as intended, when you wrote `height issue` on the title of question, what was your ideal scenario that made you think this is an issue? Did you want to Calendar View be scrollable? Did you want the whole View be scrollable? Or did you want the calendar change font size dynamically to fit in such a narrow space?

Comment: I dont want any scroll .I want that my calendar  should be adjusted in a view on even it  is big screen or small like phones .It should be ideal  should be fully shown not cutting .or over flow as shown in picture